# L'Intermédiaire des mathématiciens

Tags: ho.history-overview, journals

Does anybody know if the journal L'Intermédiaire des mathématiciens is on the web anywhere?  Failing that, does anybody know of a library that has all or even some of the issues?

Thanks for any help.

Cheers, Scott

Comment: I changed the spelling to what I assume is intended, as it might (in particular as it was not only the accents) help somebody searching.

Comment: Some scans: http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/toc/?PPN=PPN599473517 , http://www.archive.org/details/lintermdiairede01lemogoog


Answer (score 10, accepted):

Five minutes of googling resulted in the following page at the University of Michigan, which contains the full text of most volumes of this journal :

http://mirlyn.lib.umich.edu/Record/009995560

Comment: I got there with google too, but I assumed something different was expected...


Comment: What else could the OP possibly want?

Comment: What I would want is a web page accessible from outside the US. 
I have trouble understanding why the copyright prevents access to a
French journal except for viewers in the US. 

Comment: @FranzLemmermeyer Use a VPN.

Comment: What is the status of the dispute between the French government and Google about allowing access to such things on the web?

Answer (score 8):

Volume 13-14 is available here, and accessible also from outside the US:

https://archive.org/details/lintermdiairede01lemogoog

EDIT: Oops, I just saw that this information was already present in a comment by Thomas Riepe. Meanwhile, I found that Volumes 1-14 are available here, and accessible also from outside the US:

http://www.bookprep.com/book/mdp.39015065219977